What is the "compression force" in spaghettification?

15.2 (a) $M=0.5M_{\odot}$, $a=0.49\times10^9\mathrm{ms^{-2}}\approx4\times10^7g$. (b) A standing astronaut will be subject to a stretching tidal force. The gravitational acceleration felt by the feet is $3479\mathrm{\  ms^{-2}}\approx355g$ larger than that felt by the head. If the astronaut lies tangentially, (s)he will experience a compressing force of $177g$.

I am confused about the solution to (b). The question was about a spaceship orbiting around a neutron star with period of 0.1993 seconds. In (b), it was asking about what would happen to the astronaut when (s)he stands vertical and tangential to orbit. Vertical was obvious, but in the answer it mentions a "compressing force" in the tangential position. Can someone explain this force?

That's the same compression as in how the tides work; Spaghettification is always referred to as tidal for good reasons!

Well, how does the compression caused by tidal force works? I know theoretically but I don't know the math. It's also interesting that the compression force is half of the difference in gravitional acceleration. Why is it like this?

That's just the linear approximation; if you have a varying pull over a region and you pick a centre from which to zero-in and compare the pull strengths, you will simply find that the Taylor's expansion kind of pull at the general point will be pulling out in one direction and pushing in in the other direction. That's just the basic mathematical behaviour near any point that you pick as your mean. It is not very insightful. You can look up how the simplistic model of the Moon alone giving us two tidal bulges. It is the exact same theory.
